# Maven download dependencies

Tags: maven

I don't know if there is a better title for this post (please suggest) but the situation is this: in my `.m2/repository` folder there are some dependencies with all the configuration files and the corresponing `jar` but in others I have the config files but not the `jar`. For instance, in `.m2/repository/ant/ant/1.5/` I have the files:

```
_maven.repositories
ant-1.5.pom
ant-1.5.pom.lastUpdated
ant-1.5.pom.sha1
```

and `ant-1.5.jar` is missing. Is there a way to add these missing `jar`'s to the local repository?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Delete the folder `.m2/repository/ant` and restart your build..sometimes this happens if the network connection is not stable or fails or if you give wrong coordinates ....

Comment: I'd like to do it for all the dependencies in that state. With your solution I should rebuild all my projects and that's not a happy task for me :P

Comment: If you have such issues Hm...Don't you use a CI solution like Jenkins ? So you should be able delete the whole local cache `.m2/repository/`... ? Why do you need to rebuild all of your projects? I would have expected that you have many errors if some of the jar's can't found or at least `[WARNING] ...` in your build...Do you use a repository manager ?

Comment: I've heard about Jenkins but I'm not using it (yet). In fact, I was doing some checking in my local repository due to a new project I'm starting to work in and I found this issue. I was wondering if there is some way to do some *"local repository maintenance"*, do you get what I mean?

Comment: I got it. The point is your projects should be first in version control and from there it shouldn't be a big issue to rebuilt them. If you have more than 10 projects than you are doing it wrong and you should do them via Jenkins or something similar...And the best maintenance I know of is simply delete it completely and build your project...btw. The local repository is not a **repository** it is only a local cache...don't mistaken that...Start using a repository manager to hold the built artifacts in a reproducible manner...

Comment: So you're saying that there's not any `mvn update-local-repository` command or something like that, am I correct? Pitty, but being a local cache as you say, it's not worthy to worry about this, right? Please post your comments as an answer to accept it as the correct one. Thanks for your time

Comment: Unfortunately I have to say your conclusion is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is your projects should be first in version control and from there it shouldn't be a big issue to rebuilt them. If you have more than 10 projects than you are doing it wrong and you should do them via Jenkins or something similar...And the best maintenance I know of is simply delete it completely and build your project...btw. The local **repository** is not a repository it is only a **local cache** don't mistaken that...Start using a repository manager to hold the built artifacts in a reproducible manner...